# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Carousel that allows for fixed height but varying image widths?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, varying

I'm trying to figure how to adjust the Twitter Bootstrap 3 Carousel so I can have images of fixed height but varying width in a continuous stream. Right now, when I put in the images, if they're not the full width of carousel-inner, there's a space on the right side, [like so](http://pratimamani.com/GD_example1#carousel-2):

Instead of this space, I'd just like to be able to see the next image. A good example of [what I'm looking for is the following](http://spires.ws/project-5/p9vuc5akkczvl5pdn1mhm2qh4sgmnc)

What I also like about this one is that it collapses to be regular vertical scrolling on mobile instead of trying to stay as a slideshow.

The closest I've got is the bootply code, which uses the grid to get multiple images in carousel-inner, but it does fixed-width-varying-height which is the reverse of what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your given example, maybe you could also try [flowsider](http://www.flowslider.com/)